# error: expected '>' before numeric constant #define BOOT_PROTOCOL 0x00

Tags: c++

> \xx_yy.h:111:25: error: expected '>' before numeric constant

```
 #define BOOT_PROTOCOL   0x00
```

> \abcd.h:200:25: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOT_PROTOCOL'

```
 template <const uint8_t BOOT_PROTOCOL>
```

My code:

```
template <const uint8_t BOOT_PROTOCOL>
HIDBoot<BOOT_PROTOCOL>::HIDBoot(USB *p) :
HID(p),
qNextPollTime(0),
bPollEnable(false) {
    Initialize();

    for(int i = 0; i < epMUL(BOOT_PROTOCOL); i++) {
        pRptParser[i] = NULL;
    }
    if(pUsb)
        pUsb->RegisterDeviceClass(this);
```

I am trying to fix this error for a while now. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Pick **one programming language**. C or C++, which one is it?!

Comment: Please show several lines in context.

Comment: The error comes from `g++` which is a *C++* compiler, so please don't tag C.

Comment: Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BOOT_PROTOCOL` is the name of a preprocessor `#define` macro.  The *preprocessor* will change all references of `BOOT_PROTOCOL` to `0x00` before the *compiler* then sees the altered code.

So, this code:

```
template <const uint8_t BOOT_PROTOCOL>
```

will get changed to this:

```
template <const uint8_t 0x00>
```

Which is not valid C++ syntax.

You need to use a *different* name for your template parameter, eg:

```
template <const uint8_t BootProtocol>
HIDBoot<BootProtocol>::HIDBoot(USB *p) :
    HID(p),
    qNextPollTime(0),
    bPollEnable(false)
{
    Initialize();

    for(int i = 0; i < epMUL(BootProtocol); i++) {
        pRptParser[i] = NULL;
    }
    if(pUsb)
        pUsb->RegisterDeviceClass(this);
```

If you want the parameter to have a default value of 0, you can then use your macro for that, eg:

```
template <const uint8_t BootProtocol = BOOT_PROTOCOL>
```

Which the *preprocessor* will change to this:

```
template <const uint8_t BootProtocol = 0x00>
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'HIDBoot<BootProtocol>::HIDBoot(USB*)'

Second error occurred after implementing the above fix. Beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Then remove the default value from the constructor implementation's template, and use the default (if you want one) in the class template instead: `template <const uint8_t BootProtocol = BOOT_PROTOCOL> class HIDBoot { ... public: HIDBoot(USB *p); ... }; ... template <const uint8_t BootProtocol> HIDBoot<BootProtocol>::HIDBoot(USB *p) { ... }`